# Best practices for naming category methods in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, naming-conventions, objective-c-category

I've stumbled into one of two classic programming problems. I'm writing a Cocoa framework which is basically a collection of (mostly) helpful methods in categories of the most-used Foundation classes. My question is how do I name these extra methods in my categories for said classes? Should I go with a prefix or prefix-less naming convention (e.g. `- (void)doSomething` vs `- (void)myDoSomething`)?

I became unsure when reading the Cocoa documentation:

> Use prefixes when naming classes, protocols, functions, constants, and
>   typedef structures. Do not use prefixes when naming methods; methods
>   exist in a name space created by the class that defines them. Also,
>   don’t use prefixes for naming the fields of a structure

and looking at Mike's code examples in friday q&a series (e.g. method names in `MARefCounting` have prefixes in [building reference count](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-16-lets-build-reference-counting.html) article).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the documentation you quoted takes into account categories on classes you don't own. It's just trying to say that if you have defined `MyClass` you don't also need to name your methods `my_doThis`, because there isn't anything they can collide with.

In this case, it would probably be safest to use a prefix. If you left off the prefix and Apple ended up adding the same method in a future release, then your category implementation would override Apple's, which may lead to unexpected behaviors.

Even worse, sometimes you might be replacing an internally defined method (they don't always start with a `_`), which may result in internal inconsistencies within the framework, making problems much more difficult to debug.